# Allocation of array of size very large

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-arrays

How can create an array of size very large?? Well i am not able to create an array of size INT_MAX.. how could be achieve this.?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#define SIZE 2147483647

int main() {    
   int *array;    
   unsigned int i;

   array = malloc(sizeof(int) * SIZE);    
   if(array == NULL)    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate that much memory");
      return 1;    }

   for(i=0; i<1; i++)    {
      array[0] = 0;    
   }    

   free(array); 
}
```

Comment: *i am not able to create an array of size INT_MAX* - That's not what your code is doing.  It is attempting to create an array of sizeof(int) * INT_MAX.

Answer (score 5):

You're almost certainly hitting a platform limit. If you only have a 32-bit address space, 4G is as much as you can hope to address. In reality, it will be much less since part of the address space will be taken up by other things.

With a 64-bit address space, it may be possible but, once you get to that level of allocation, you should ask yourself if it's actually necessary.

A way of solving the problem is to use out-of-memory storage such as disk and only bring into memory what's needed.

In other words, segment the data structure into (for example) 1M chunks and process it 1M at a time.

There are plenty of caching algorithms you can use to do this efficiently depending on the usage patterns of your data structure.

For example, for truly sequential access, you could have one chunk in memory at a time. For truly random access, you may want to have several chunks in memory at a time in a cache scenario - each in-memory structure stores both the 1M of data and it's location in the out-of-memory storage so you can use LRU algorithms and write-back of dirty data, and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is not the allocation itself but the seemingly simple expression `sizeof(int) * SIZE`. The result of that operation is `0x1FFFFFFFC` if `int` has 4 bytes. This needs 33 bits to be represented. If your platform only has a `size_t` type of 32 bit the result of the multiplication wraps around (`size_t` is unsigned) and gives you `0xFFFFFFFC`.

If you'd had just used the 33 bit value above in your call to malloc, your compiler would probably have told you that that number isn't representable.

Comment: size_t is an unsigned type, thus the result is not "undefined", but truncated to the number of bits of size_t. Which gives a smaller size than expected, with the chance that malloc succeeds, but returning a much smaller chunk of memory than required...

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an array of minimum 4GB size. Are you sure you have that much free memory?

Comment: More important than free memory is address space.  If your machine doesn't have enough bits per pointer to access a particular index of the array, then it doesn't matter if you have enough free memory (and virtual memory makes free memory mostly a moot point anyway).

Comment: But if there is not enough address space doesn't it mean that OS doesn't see enough free space. Aren't our answers kind of the same? May be I should put "...that much addressable free memory".

Comment: It's really address space not free memory that matters. It could be satisfied perfectly well without free memory as long as sufficient virtual memory exists to commit for it, or on systems (like default Linux) with overcommit where they *don't care* if physical memory/storage exists to back virtual memory and just crash later if it's not available...

Answer (score -1):

So far everyone is trying to answer your question as asked, but I'd like to take another approach.  In my experience, it is rare that you actually need an array of the type/size you are trying to allocation.  There are often other ways of doing what you need without creating such a huge structure (parse arrays, stacks, queues, maps).

I'm curious what you want to DO with this array . . . I'm betting you don't actually need it if we understood what problem you were trying to solve.

On the other hand, if this is an intellectual exercise (like how big can I allocate), there are approaches to answering those kinds of questions as well.

If you want to play . . . what is it your are actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: And as a second question . . . why C?  Why not C# or C++ or many other languages.  Don't get me wrong, I learned C when Kernighan and Ritchie where writing about it and made a lot of money writing C code over the years . . . but most of us have moved on . . . why C for this problem now?

Comment: Why learn Newtonian Mechanics when the evidence suggests that the assumptions do not apply universally? Because for some uses, it is a simple enough system, because sometimes you have to look at how things were done, because sometimes it is still valid and because for some applications the new approach works well and for others it is very bad.

Comment: Right, but I'm trying to engage this guy and get him to reveal more about his problem and his solution space.  As I said, C is a great language and as you point out it is simple and easy to learn.  Is that the goal here though?  What is the "real problem" under the stated problem?  I'm guessing this isn't about creating a big array of integers.  The user is trying to accomplish something . . . what is it?

Comment: This is not an answer